# jquery get array checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have in my document 2 checkbox arrays. One is `engines[]` and one is `searchId[]`.

```
$("input:checkbox[@name='searchId[]']:checked").each(function() i use this to capture all the values from the searchId[] checkboxes (only if checked).
$("input:checkbox[@name='engines[]']:checked").each(function() same thing for engines
```

the problem is that it the selector gets all the checked checkboxes in the document regardless of their name. How can I make it get only the array I wish to get?

some code for a better understanding:

```
$("#startSearch").live("click", function(event){
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    $("input:checkbox[@name='searchId']:checked").each(function(){

                        $.getJSON("startsearch.php",{searchId: $(this).val()},function(data){
                            alert($(this).val());
                            $('#status_' + $(this).val()).text(data.status);
                            $('#results_' + $(this).val()).text(data.results);
                            $('#date_' + $(this).val()).text(data.date);
                            $('#totalResults_' + $(this).val()).text(data.totalResults);
                        });
                    });
                });

$("#submit").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $("input[@name='engines[]']:checked").each(function(){

                        $.getJSON( "addsearch.php", { inputString: $('#inputString').val(),searchString: $('#searchString').val(), engine: $(this).val() }, function(data){
                            //$('#searchTable tbody tr:first').empty();
                            var row = '<tr><td><span id ="status_'+data.id+'">'+data.status+'</span></td>'+
                                '<td>'+data.search+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data.category+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data.engine+'</td>'+
                                '<td><span id = "results_"'+data.id+'">0</span></td>'+
                                '<td><span id ="date_'+data.id+'">'+data.date+'</span></td>'+
                                '<td><span id ="totalResults_'+data.id+'">0</span></td>'+
                                '<td style="width: 96px;"><div class="actions"><ul>'+
                                '<li><input class="radio" name="searchId[]" type="checkbox" value="'+data.id+'" /></li>'+
                                '<li><a class="action1" href="#">1</a></li>'+
                                '<li><a class="action4" href="#">4</a></li>'+
                                '</ul></div></td>';
                            $('#searchTable tbody').after(row);
                        });
                    });

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

1. The `@attr` selectors were completely removed on jQuery 1.3, if you are using a jQuery version > 1.2, simply remove the `@` sign from the selector.
2. The `[` and `]` characters need to be double escaped.

   ```
   $("input:checkbox[name='searchId\\[\\]']:checked").each(function () {
     //..
   });
   ```

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

> > In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the '@' symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.

The full list of characters that [need to be escaped](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors#Special_characters_in_selectors): `#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/`